# If w is a complex root of 1. Find the value of w^4+w^8

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $w$ is a complex root of 1. Find the value of $w^4+w^8$

**Why** does complex root of 1 always mean that $w^3=1$ ? Why not $w^2$ ?

Back to the question, here's what I did:

$$w^8+w^4=w^2(w^3)^2+w(w^3)$$

Since $w^3=1$

$$=w^2+w$$

---

My book continued  this idea to :

Since $1+w+w^2=0$ (**I don't know why**)

Then:

$$w^4+w^8=w^2+w=-1$$

How did the book do this?

Comment: It *doesn't* always mean that $w^3=1$. You're right. There is some missing information/assumptions here.

Comment: If we accept that $w^3=1$, or that the book specifically meant a cubic root (in my opinion that is Very iffy), then
$$0=w^3-1=(w-1)(w^2+w+1).$$ So if $w\neq1$ we get $w^2+w+1=0$.

Comment: So the term "complex root of 1" does not necessarily mean $w^3$ ? Because I found it weird too, why can't they just called it 3rd root of unity.

Comment: Most likely a typo/omission.

Comment: Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen , can you post it as an answer? I understood

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok thank you. But it's weird coz its repeated in many questions.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you didn't misread "cube root of $1$"? If that happens once, such misreadings have a tendency to perpetuate.

Comment: @DanielFischer Im positive. Infact it has two types of questions. Some questions say w is a cube root of 1 and other say w is a complex root of 1.

Comment: Okay, then they probably meant "complex cube root of $1$" to indicate that $\omega\neq 1$ [although $1$ is also a complex number, people often use "complex" to mean "non-real" in such situations] and forgot the "cube". You could send a report about that mistake to the authors.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you alottt Daniel. Yes I will.

Comment: ...or perhaps the textbook *defined* $\omega$ as a particular cube root of unity...

Comment: @JpMcCarthy I wish they had, but No they haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\omega$ is **Cube Root** of unity

$$x^3=1$$

$$x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=0$$

$x=1$ is one solution, other two are complex

$$(z^2+z+1)=0$$
$$z=\omega,\omega^2$$

Comment: Isn't it better to replace z by x in this case?

Comment: @TheArtist we generally use $z$ for complex numbers

Comment: don't you think when you say z= $\omega$ , $\omega^2$ . Which are the two other roots. So one who sees this question might get confused with $w$ and $w^2$ In my question??

Comment: There are Exactly 3 **Cube Roots** of Unity, $1,\omega,\omega^2$, And I think your book meant **Complex Cube Roots** not just Complex Roots

Comment: And there is no variable called $x$ in my question. So I think it would be nice if you can change these conventions??